# iOS - Unable to locate the location of Exception

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

**What is happening?**

I am getting an exception in a program where a function is to be called On a Button tap on a custom view within `contentView` of a `UItableViewCell`

**What i have tried?**

1) I tried to add a Global Exception point in the `Breakpoints Navigator`

2) Checked Zombie Detection from **Instruments**

3) Breakpoints in the functions that should be called

**Crash Log that i receive?**

```
-[UIImageView nextPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa7d5f20
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView nextPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa7d5f20'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x023e11e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01fc98e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0247e243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x023d150b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x023d10ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01fdb880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x009463b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x00946345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    8   UIKit                               0x00a47bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x00a47fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    10  UIKit                               0x00a47243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    11  UIKit                               0x00cdc2e3 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7166
    12  UIKit                               0x00985a5a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    13  UIKit                               0x00986971 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1021
    14  UIKit                               0x009585f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    15  UIKit                               0x00942353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0236a77f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0236a10b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x023871ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x023869d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x023867eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0381a5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0381a42b GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x00944f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    24  IslamBox                            0x000029bc main + 76
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x034b3701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

> **What else could i do as the functions are registered in the Nib file?**

**UPDATE:** as the log says -[UIImageView nextpage] is unrecognized however the next page is in the ViewController. as the custom view is the ViewController's view  added to the cell's contentView.

Comment: Check where you call nextPage:. If you add your code, it will be better to help you.

Comment: can you share the code of your button selector and cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath there is a view controller whose view is added the controller contains its function defination

Comment: Actually the View with the registered IBAction in the viewcontroller is Button. However the Log says that [UIImageView nextPage] cannot be found. Shouldn't it be [viewcontroller nextPage]?

Comment: Please edit your answer with your custom view implementation and button selector. This will help others to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I need to retain my ViewController , or keep a strong reference to it if using ARC. If I assign it to cell.contentView as a local variable, it's not going to be around any more when `nextPage:` gets called. (The error shows that its memory has been released and re-used for a different type of object.)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be just the fact that the object in your xib file is set as `UIImageView` instead of your own custom subclass of `UIImageView` ?

When the view is allocated from your xib, it will be a UIImageView. Having it linked to something different in your .h or .m won't change that.

Change it here : [image]

Comment: Actually the View with the registered IBAction in the viewcontroller is Button. However the Log says that [UIImageView nextPage] cannot be found. Shouldn't it be [viewcontroller nextPage]?

Comment: is the method `nextPage` an `IBAction` ? Or is it a method called by yourself ? If it is, can you share the part of your code, when `nextPage` is called ?

Comment: yes its an IBAction and it is registered on a UIButton for touchupinside in the InterfaceBuilder. So there is no code to share however can share a screenshot

Comment: i have checked the View is UIButton, the delegate object is of the viewcontroller. SO kind of logical.

Answer (score 0):

if every time crash on [UIImageView nextPage:],
you can try

```
@implementation UIImageView(Test)

- (id)nextPage:(id)noUse
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

and set a breakpoint on the return.

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing without adding or modifying any code by creating a symbolic breakpoint. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html